# Postgres SQL state: 22P02

Tags: postgresql

I need to run the following query in Postgres:

```
select left(file_date, 10) as date, lob_name, devicesegment, sum(conversion_units::numeric) as units
from bac_search.dash_search_data
where (lob_name= 'Mortgage' and file_date::date between (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days') and CURRENT_DATE)
      or (lob_name= 'Loans' and file_date::date between (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days') and CURRENT_DATE)
group by file_date, lob_name, devicesegment
order by file_date, lob_name, devicesegment;
```

Despite setting conversion_units to numeric, it is giving me the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
> SQL state: 22P02
> ```

Of note, I've done some unit testing and when I run this query for Mortgage and delete the line for Loans, it works fine.  I've isolated the problem to `conversion_units::numeric` for `Loans`. Besides the usual conversion (as I've specified here), I'm not sure what else to try. I read through the questions with this error, but they don't seem to mirror my problem. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently `conversion_units` is a string which can hold values not convertible to `numeric`.

You immediate problem can be solved this way:

```
SUM(NULLIF(conversion_units, '')::numeric)
```

but there can be other values.

You might try to use regexp to match convertible strings:

```
SUM((CASE WHEN conversion_units ~ E'^\\d(?:\\.\\d)*$' THEN conversion_units END)::numeric)
```

Answer (score 1):

For future searchers:

I got this error (Postgres SQL state: 22P02) while trying to import data from csv.

with this command:

COPY my_end_table 
FROM 'D:\check\sample.csv' WITH CSV

Solution: turns out the csv should not contain headers....

Answer (score 0):

The problem in order column in `csv`.

The order in `csv` file must be the same column name in copy syentext.