# invalid input syntax for type numeric: "1,257.00"

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a table and copy the contents of a csv file to it. I am getting an error with decimal values in the csv file.

I tried to use the float, double and numeric types. All of them give the same error.

```
create temporary table t (header_text varchar(300), 
                                     product_text varchar(2300),
                                    picture varchar(300),
                                    category varchar(200),
                                    sub_category varchar(200),
                                    going_price NUMERIC,
                                    compatibility varchar(300),
                                    brand varchar(200),
                                    network_std varchar(200),
                                    is_standalone int,
                                    data_sec int,
                                    budget_lvl int,
                                    voice_ass int,
                                    entertainment int,
                                    child_friendly int,
                                    room int,
                                    has_gateway int,
                                    needs_gateway int);
```

Error when trying:

```
copy t FROM 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\DatabaseX.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV Header ;
```

Error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "1,257.00" CONTEXT: 
>   COPY t, line 128, column going_price: "1,257.00" SQL state: 22P02

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123872/postgres-sql-state-22p02) ?

Comment: Float and double data types don't really accept the comma in their format. The decimal point is fine but the comma will make the data appear as a string.

Comment: @tshimkus When I check the csv file, the value does not have any "," in it.

Comment: Where is it coming from then? If the document was opened and saved in a program like Excel it might be inserting the comma. How does it look in a plain text CSV file on line 128?